# TCP spurious retransmission and duplicate ACKs for Virtualbox guests when bridged

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, tcp

Using Virtualbox 5.2.8 on Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit I noticed that sometimes TCP connections stall. The guests are Linux (various distributions). When I investigated the issue I found that this happens only, if the NICs are in bridged mode, the problem disappears entirely when I configure them as NAT. Specifically, in bridged mode for some but not for all connections I get massive amounts of TCP retransmissions. In particular, the typical sequence as seen in Wireshark is like

- local -> remote: TCP Spurious Retransmission (with or without PSH)
- remote -> local: TCP Dup ACK
- remote -> local: TCP Retransmission (many, many)

I could provide a pcap file but I claim that details at this level are irrelevant since in NAT mode this behavior does not appear. The observed behavior is visible in the guest with wireshark, on the host with wireshark, and through the capturing facility of VirtualBox; in all cases it follows the same pattern.

The only setting for bridged mode is the setting for promiscious mode, and that seems irrelevant (the observed behavior occurs at any setting). Also, the type of NIC is irrelevant, I tried  the default Intel PRO/1000 MT and virtio - no difference. The guest-specific log files don't show anything related.

I also tried bridging to wired ethernet and wireless - no difference.

The problem is somewhat similar to [this ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15014), however, I have no problem sending an receiving ICMP packets to the involved hosts (no duplicate ICMP packets).
The problem did not appear on Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit.

The host is configured as defined by the vendor, there are no custom firewall rules; the host OS is up-to-date. The guests also have just the off-the-shelf configuration, nothing special.

What could be the cause and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is a brand new HP notebook that comes with various HP addons installed, among which is *HP Velocity*. After causing a few nasty blue screens (due to the driver ipeaklwf.sys) I found out that HP Velocity comes with some interesting features, such as a *TCP Optimizer* that *optimizes bandwidth utilization by minimizing TCP overhead [...]* - whatever this means.

As of the blue screens [several users recommended](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems-and-Recovery/Blue-screen-DRIVER-IRQL-NOT-LESS-OR-EQUAL/td-p/6474242) to deinstall HP Velocity. When I did this, too, the problem disappered.